# ListView Headers same as Android settings

Tags: android, listview, layout

I would like to implement a section header like on my listview. The one that can be found on android's settings menu. Is there a native way of implementing this without using 3rd party resources? Thanks!

Settings Menu on Android with Section Headers. Sample image.

[image]

[Android Settings](http://sadpanda.us/images/1827264-K9QBSO1.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this as the title and above listview

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello, World"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>
```

Comment: I tried placing this on a separate xml layout and added it via listview.addHeader() method. It works fine. Thanks! But assuming I have a need for at least 3 headers, would that mean I need to make 3 listviews?

Comment: pretty much, you'll have to divide your listview into 3 parts. this is the only way i was able to do it as these headers otherwise are only available in preference catergory